# What is faster: Python3's 'len' or numpys shape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I have an array of coordinates:

```
points = [x,y]
```

with the (numpy) dimensions/shape: (18, 1, 2)

In matlab, to initialize an array of ones to index these points with '3', I could do this:

```
A = ones(size(points,1),1)*3'
```

How could I do this using python3 and numpy in the fastest possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal `numpy` equivalent would be

```
np.ones((points.shape[0],1))*3
```

`shape` is an attribute of an array, so accessing it is essentially instantaneous.  It doesn't have to do any calculating.

```
In [277]: points.shape
Out[277]: (18, 1, 2)
In [278]: points.size   # number of elements
Out[278]: 36
In [279]: len(points)  # size of the 1st dimension
Out[279]: 18
```

In the above `np.ones...` expression, the `shape` or `len()` is a very small part of the computation time.  It doesn't matter which you use.  But `shape` is more general, eg. `np.ones(points.shape[:2])` would give the same `(18,1)` array.

Answer (score 3):

```
    def time_compare(self):
        loops = 100000000
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(loops):
            self.value_map.shape[0]
            self.value_map[0].shape[0]
            self.value_map[0][0].shape[0]
            self.value_map[0][0][0].shape[0]
        end = time.time()
        timed = (end - start)
        print("shape={}".format(timed))

        start = time.time()
        for i in range(loops):
            len(self.value_map)
            len(self.value_map[0])
            len(self.value_map[0][0])
            len(self.value_map[0][0][0])
        end = time.time()
        timed = (end - start)
        print("len={}".format(timed))
```

> shape=102.26551818847656
>   len=87.99720764160156

len is faster than shape